# react-i18next: cant replace I18Next HOC

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, i18next, react-i18next

I am having problems updating my React app with the great `react-i18next`.

I have a HOC that "abstract" the connection to Redux. This HOC looks like this:

```js
// This is the component I used to use, but it doesn't exist anymore in v10:
import { I18n } from "react-i18next";

export const myHOC = identifier => ({
   actions, 
   translations,
}) => WrappedComponent => {

   // connnect the WrappedComponent to Redux:
   const ConnectedComponent = connect(
       // generate the mapStateToProps automatically
       mapStateToProps(),
       actions
   )

   class MyConnnector extends Component {
       // constructor:
       constructor(props, context) {
         super(props);

         // Can't say why new React new Context API doesn't bring
         // store (from Redux) and i18n (from react-i18next) are undefined here:
         console.log(context.store, context.i18n); // undefined, undefined
       }

       // then render method:
       render() {
         // If there are translation to use...
         if (translations) {
           return (
           // Return the I18n component with the previously ConnectedComponent as a child:

           // HERE! This component doesn't exists anymore. What's the best way to replace it?
           <I18n i18n={this.context.i18n} ns={[key, "commom"]}>
              <ConnnectedComponent {...this.props} />
           </I18n>
           );    
         }

         return <ConnectedComponent {...this.props} /> 
       }

   }

   return MyConnnector;
}
```

Comment: What is your exact problem with this snippet?

Comment: The first problem is: the <I18n> component doesn't exists anymore. And when I try to replace it using `withTranslation` HOC, redux and i18n instances are undefined in Context to `ConnectedComponent`.

Comment: The second problem is: I can't say why, but `this.context.store` and `this.context.i18n` are `undefined`. And they are being rendered inside Redux and i18next Providers.